# Propel: many-to-many relationship without crosstable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, propel

I have recently got an assignment from my school, where I have to create a Propel Schema for ORM.
This isn't really a Problem, but one of the requirements is to connect two of those tables with a many-to-many relationship.

Normally, you would do that with a crosstable (holding the attributes from both tables), but our teacher said that this is also possible WITHOUT such a crosstable (and even is a requirement).

How would one go into creating such in Propel?

The ERD in Question:

http://files.f-o-g.eu/b8f8a9

(I am stuck at VIP <-> Einladung)

So far I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="orm1" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <table name="einladung" phpName="Einladung">
            <column name="nummer" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
            <column name="fbuffet" type="BOOLEAN" />
            <column name="splatz" type="INTEGER" />
    </table>
    <table name="sorganisation" phpName="SpendenOrganisation">
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR" size="255" primaryKey="true" required="true" />
            <column name="adresse" type="VARCHAR" size="255" />
    </table>
    <table name="wveranstaltung" phpName="WVeranstaltung">
            <column name="titel" type="VARCHAR" size="255" primaryKey="true" required="true" />
            <column name="datum" type="DATE" required="true" />
            <column name="ort" type="VARCHAR" size="255"/>

    </table>
    <table name="vip" phpName="Vip">
            <column name="id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
            <column name="vname" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true" />
            <column name="nname" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true" />
    </table>
</database>
```

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: Wish it was in english. I can't even seem to find the common link between those tables!

Comment: To translate: left side (VIP) (vorname= firstname, nachname=lastname); right side: Einladung (invitation) (freies buffet = free  buffet, sitzplatz = seat, nummer = number); between (bekommt = get) (spenden betrag = donation amount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create a m-to-m relation without a cross table.

I guess your `VIP -> Einladung` relation is just wrong. It should probably be a 1-to-n relation.

Comment: Well, the Relationship is correct (that's the specification we got). Anyways, as I guessed, it's not possible without such a cross table. Going to accept your Answer.